# Unable to add more than 20 extensions on selenium chromedriver

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I am using this code:

```
chrome_options.add_extension(r'path to extension 1')
chrome_options.add_extension(r'path to extension 2')
...
chrome_options.add_extension(r'path to extension 20')


driver =  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:\chromedriver.exe" , chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

I want to add 100 extensions to chrome for reasons, but when I add  anything more than 20 extensions, I see this error:

```
 driver =  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:\chromedriver.exe" , chrome_options=chrome_options)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vanzw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\vanzw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\vanzw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\vanzw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1322, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\vanzw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 303, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\vanzw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 264, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\vanzw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get around this limit of 20, and what causes this limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been unable to completely solve this, but I have found that the 20 extension limit somehow relates to the windows 20 socket limit:
https://forum.powerbasic.com/forum/user-to-user-discussions/programming-the-internet/771798-maximum-unique-tcp-connections-allowed-by-license-in-windows-10